# Python code works on JupyterNotebook (local) but not on Visual Studio Code (ssh)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, ssh, local

So, I have a piece of code written in Python which works perfectly fine on my local Jupyter Notebook, BUT when I run the same piece of code on Visual Studio Code it doesn't work.

This is the code:

```
for i in df.index:
        for j in columns:

            millis = round(int(df.loc[i, j].value / 1e+6))
            millis = np.array([millis])

            for x in millis:

                seconds = (x/1000)%60
                seconds = int(seconds)

                minutes = (x/(1000*60))%60
                minutes = int(minutes)

                hours = (x/(1000*60*60))%24

                hour = "%d:%d:%d" % (hours, minutes, seconds)

                df.loc[i,j] = hour
```

So, this is to turn previously converted columns from timedelta to it's original values.

Everything works fine until the last line `df.loc[i, j] = hour`

For some strange reason, it works fine on my local Jupyter Notebook but that particular line doesn't work on Visual Studio Code.

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Does it throw an error? Or the result is incorrect? What is your sample data and what is the expected result?

Comment: Please provide your post request with the whole code snippet if possible and error/exception/traceback message(s) if any.

Comment: Have you tried debugging?

Comment: It was a problem with pandas version. 

Super weird! Can't believe a simple dataframe.loc won't work on a version a it did on other version

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with pandas version. Super weird! Can't believe a simple dataframe.loc won't work on a version a it did on other version

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a certain pluggin that makes your code work in JupiterNotebook that you don't have in VSC? Check your pluggins are try to install the same ones on VSC if you see any pluggins that you dont have.

Comment: It was a problem with pandas version. 

Super weird! Can't believe a simple dataframe.loc won't work on a version a it did on other version